# Git & Github Repository name

Tags: git, github

I renamed my repository in GitHub
but it didn't change in git command line. What do I have to do to change it there also?

Comment: Did you read https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository? That tells you how to update your remotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this command:

```
 git remote set-url origin new_url
```

as it says in the documentation:

- https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url
- https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-repository

Comment: Thanks a lot sir